# How do I enter an item ID from one column into another

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

I am currently developing a SharePoint site for managing contract tenders. The site is currently laid as follows: I have a subsite in the main site collection.  This has custom lists which holds the overview information on all our tenders.  The tenders are split into separate site collections by year, each with it's own content database.

Now to manage each tender, a document set is created. I have several lookup drop down lists where the users select information.  It has been configured this way so I can customise the data in other ways.

The issue starts, from when I want it to update the list in the tender over view which is in a separate site collection.  I can save information to it successfully if it is a string, number or date field.  I cannot if it is a lookup. I can get the ID of the item out of SharePoint but when I try to enter it into the column, it fails. I have made sure the column names are correct , and it is the correct value, but to no avail.

The error code which I am getting is

> {"error":{"code":"-2130575155,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldValueException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Cannot
>   complete this action.\u000a\u000aPlease try again."}}}

Realise it's a bit of a long post, but thought if you had the details it would be easier for you to understand what I am doing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found the answer to my problem, turns out I had a bit of a dumb moment.   I did not construct the dictionary correctly.  I did not put the columns in the correct order, and this caused the issue.  I recreated the dictionary with the columns in order and this resolved my issue.